# Transformar um conteúdo em uma imagem

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um projeto em Windows Forms para ajudar a minha empresa à gerar assinaturas de email automatizado para nossos colaboradores.

Eu tenho no caso um windows forms único que contém um Tab Control, com Dados e Preview. Na tab preview existe um PictureBox com algumas Labels por cima dela que é onde será inserido os dados do colaborador.

Minha pergunta é, como eu posso fazer com que seja salvo o conteúdo inteiro dessa tab Preview em uma imagem? (.jpg, .png, etc)

Segue imagens de exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caso o cliente de e-mail seja o outlook: Já pensou em desenvolver um plugin para o outlook? Ao fazer isso é possível alterar a assinatura do remetente (em texto).

Comment: Não é para outlook.. E sim, já havia pensado dessa maneira se fosse o caso. :(

Comment: Aqui na empresa tem um sistema semelhante, onde a assinatura é gerada em HTML. Ao gerar a assinatura abre o navegador e o usuário usa o CTRL + A e o CTRL + C para copiar e colar na assinatura do e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira seria usar os classes `Bitmap` e `Graphics` para fazer um *screenshot*. Não testei e nem sei se vai funcionar, mas segue um código que mostra um exemplo de como fazer *screenshot* de todo o seu desktop - talvez possa adaptá-la a tirar só da sua programa:

```
//Criar um novo bitmap.
var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

// Criar um objecto de graphics do bitmap.
var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

// Tira a screenshot do canto superior esquero até o canto inferior direito
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                            0,
                            0,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

// Salvar o screenshot na pasta desejada
bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

<sub>Inspirado por [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363008/1245766) do SOen.</sub>